# Does Microsoft Word (2019, NOT 365) Text-To-Speech support custom word pronunciation?

Tags: microsoft-word, tts

Just discovered TTS and it's a godsend but for things like names, the pronunciation is getting slaughtered. I can live with it, but I'd prefer that I didn't have to do so.

After a few google searches, I came upon this - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh362825(v=office.14)

So I can define a lexicon for custom name pronunciation, which is great... but the document I looked through talks about lexicon files, and grammar documents, but doesn't say how I bring those into Microsoft Word, which is the entire thing I've been trying to do.

Am I way off base here? Is there a better option?